# Azure SQL Database connection exception (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException is thrown )

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, azure-sql-database

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I started from scratch. I just want to use the SQL database hosted on Azure in my project.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'myname'. This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '00dbcf81-35eb-4d92-b022-da1bca001e5f'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.

What I did:

1. I set up the web.config connection string using the one Azure Management Portal provided. I copied and pasted directly.
2. I set up the firewall on my computer -  both outbound and inbound with port 1433 allowed
3. In azure management portal, I put my IP address in the list.
4. I can use my password and username to connect the Azure db using SQL server management studio successfully. Everything works fine.
5. I also set "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server"

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1-20140927090028;User ID=myid;Password={mypsw};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I checked all the posts here and didn't find much information useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the connection string/code you're trying to connect with? Other than that, I'm afraid the only other advice I can offer is to double check the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY. Solved.

PAY ATTENTION to the connection string Azure portal provides. You have to remove the brackets for the password. THAT'S IT!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is something wrong with the credentials given as stated below
Double check your Username and Password carefully.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): **Login failed for user 'myname'**. This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '00dbcf81-35eb-4d92-b022-da1bca001e5f'. Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I double checked and I'm pretty sure psw and name are correct.